# What to use instead of css `line-height` to avoid spoiling Unicode tables?

Tags: unicode, css

Is there an alternative to css `line-height` that does not ruin the look of Unicode tables (tables drawn with [Unicode box-drawing characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character):

```
┌─────────────┐
│  character  │
├─────────────┤
│ Donald Duck │
└─────────────┘
```

(Stack Overflow and others use `line-height: 130%;` or similar to improve the visual appearance of posts, I want to have a neat alternative to propose to SE - particularly [for dba.se](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1126/1396) - so we can use unicode art for tables without it looking naff.)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What have you tried, and how did it fail? You aren't new here, please provide with necessary details.

Comment: Do you see the broken lines on your browser? I want to have a neat alternative to propose to SE (particularly [for dba.se](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/1126/1396)) so we can use unicode art for tables without it looking naff.

Comment: As for what I've tried, I've tried removing the `line-height` and that looks just fine to me, but I anticipate SE refusing to change the look of the site like that and I'm looking for an alternative they might prefer.

Comment: I don't see any broken lines in chrome or safari

Comment: The answer is, I'm afraid, it depends on the font.

Comment: @MrLister that's interesting, and I find it surprising: do you have any info about why it does?

Comment: @Juan I get broken lines on Chrome/W7 with default fonts

Comment: What is your HTML and CSS code, and exactly how do they ruin the look of Unicode tables, and what are “Unicode tables”?

Comment: It seems that by “Unicode table” you mean something commonly known as “Ascii art” or “Ascii graphics” and that you are using box drawing characters for borders and lines. And you are not happy with “broken lines”: vertical line characters do not touch, when you have set `line-height: 130%`. You should clarify this by editing the question. Explaining why you are using Ascii art at all and why you just don’t leave `line-height` to default value (which would apparently prevent the problem) would help in deciding what types of answers would be acceptable.

Comment: @Jukka I don't think Ascii-anything is the appropriate term. Wikipedia has it as 'Box Drawing Characters' and I've added a link for clarity. As for HTML and CSS, isn't it clear that I'm talking about this very page on Stack Overflow?

Comment: The alternative to `line-height` is not setting `line-height`, or setting it to a small value. This works for me, for example, with no CSS at all: http://jsfiddle.net/Wfk7h/ . You can disable or reset `line-height` for the `<pre>` elements or your tables.

Comment: @Kobi not setting line-height is what [I've suggested](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/1126/1396), but I was hoping there might be a neat alternative that retained the line spacing but allowed the Unicode box characters to remain full line height.

Comment: I'm playing with that. Maybe you can abuse [language hints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/7586) to add an arbitrary CSS class to the code block (e.g. `<!-- language: lang-table -->`), and set the `line-height` only for that class. This can work if SQL fiddle generates the whole code block for you.

Comment: You should still show the actual HTML and CSS you are using, and what you are referring to are not tables at all; it is particularly misleading to call them tables since they are neither HTML tables nor CSS tables. And still not clear why you want to use `line-height` setting that causes the problem (according to your description).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. There is no alternative to line spacing if you want the lines to be spaced closer together. Unless you have something else in mind, but then you should elaborate.

The context to your question is vague too. Is this about the StackExchange site itself? If so, it should have been asked on https://meta.stackexchange.com/

That said, the effect does depend on the font used. In some fonts, the length of the vertical line │ is longer than in others; for instance the line is 1em long in Lucida Console and 1.17em in Consolas. So when using Consolas, you can use a maximum line-height of 1.17 before the gap becomes visible, while Lucida requires the line height to be smaller.

One possible solution I just thought of might be to create a font containing only the line drawing characters, and make the vertical lines very long. Then use it as a webfont.